# Use an Alias in Where Clause Subquery in Oracle

Tags: oracle10g, alias

i need to show some field from another table in oracle here is my query

```
SELECT
ANGGARAN.SIMPEG_PEGAWAI.ID_PEGAWAI AS KODE,
ANGGARAN.SIMPEG_PEGAWAI.NAMA,
ANGGARAN.SIMPEG_PEGAWAI.NIP,
ANGGARAN.SIMPEG_ESELON_JABATAN.JABATAN,
ANGGARAN.SIMPEG_KODE_GOLONGAN_PANGKAT.GOLONGAN,
ANGGARAN.SIMPEG_KODE_GOLONGAN_PANGKAT.PANGKAT,
    (SELECT *
            FROM (SELECT CONCAT(TO_CHAR(abs(sysdate - TO_DATE(TMT_JABATAN))/360,'9,999,999.9'),' TAHUN') 
                FROM SIMPEG_JABATAN where ID_PEGAWAI=KODE ORDER BY TMT_JABATAN desc)
    WHERE ROWNUM = 1) AS MASA_KERJA
FROM 
ANGGARAN.SIMPEG_PEGAWAI
    INNER JOIN ANGGARAN.SIMPEG_ESELON_JABATAN 
        ON ANGGARAN.SIMPEG_PEGAWAI.ESELON_JABATAN = ANGGARAN.SIMPEG_ESELON_JABATAN.ID_ESELON_JABATAN
    INNER JOIN ANGGARAN.SIMPEG_KODE_GOLONGAN_PANGKAT 
        ON ANGGARAN.SIMPEG_PEGAWAI.PANGKAT = ANGGARAN.SIMPEG_KODE_GOLONGAN_PANGKAT.ID_GOLONGAN_PANGKAT
WHERE
    ANGGARAN.SIMPEG_PEGAWAI.ST_AKTIF = 1 AND
    ANGGARAN.SIMPEG_PEGAWAI.ESELON2 <> 1 AND
    ANGGARAN.SIMPEG_PEGAWAI.PANGKAT >= 12 AND 
    ANGGARAN.SIMPEG_ESELON_JABATAN.STATUS = 1 AND
    ANGGARAN.SIMPEG_ESELON_JABATAN.ID_ESELON2=2
ORDER BY
ANGGARAN.SIMPEG_KODE_GOLONGAN_PANGKAT.SORT DESC
```

result i got

```
[Err] ORA-00904: "KODE": invalid identifier
```

the KODE come from  query `ANGGARAN.SIMPEG_PEGAWAI.ID_PEGAWAI AS KODE,` and used for this query

```
(SELECT *
        FROM (SELECT CONCAT(TO_CHAR(abs(sysdate - TO_DATE(TMT_JABATAN))/360,'9,999,999.9'),' TAHUN') 
            FROM SIMPEG_JABATAN where ID_PEGAWAI=KODE ORDER BY TMT_JABATAN desc)
WHERE ROWNUM = 1) AS MASA_KERJA
```

that i miss something ? or that could be worogn using an alias in subquery where clause in oracle database ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an identifier defined in an external query in only one level deep queries. You have to rethink your strategy. My suggestion is to remove the subquery from the select list and put it in the `FROM` clause. And add another `rownumber` column like this:

```
(SELECT 
    ID_PEGAWAI,
    CONCAT(TO_CHAR(abs(sysdate - TO_DATE(TMT_JABATAN))/360,'9,999,999.9'),' TAHUN') MASA_KERJA, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID_PEGAWAI ORDER BY TMT_JABATAN DESC) rownumber
FROM SIMPEG_JABATAN) xxx
```

And join like:

```
ON ANGGARAN.SIMPEG_PEGAWAI = xxx.ID_PEGAWAI
```

Then in the where clause you can do simply:

```
WHERE
     ....
     AND xxx.rownumber = 1
```

Complete query:

```
SELECT
  ANGGARAN.SIMPEG_PEGAWAI.ID_PEGAWAI AS KODE,
  ANGGARAN.SIMPEG_PEGAWAI.NAMA,
  ANGGARAN.SIMPEG_PEGAWAI.NIP,
  ANGGARAN.SIMPEG_ESELON_JABATAN.JABATAN,
  ANGGARAN.SIMPEG_KODE_GOLONGAN_PANGKAT.GOLONGAN,
  ANGGARAN.SIMPEG_KODE_GOLONGAN_PANGKAT.PANGKAT
FROM 
  ANGGARAN.SIMPEG_PEGAWAI
    INNER JOIN ANGGARAN.SIMPEG_ESELON_JABATAN 
      ON ANGGARAN.SIMPEG_PEGAWAI.ESELON_JABATAN = ANGGARAN.SIMPEG_ESELON_JABATAN.ID_ESELON_JABATAN
    INNER JOIN ANGGARAN.SIMPEG_KODE_GOLONGAN_PANGKAT 
      ON ANGGARAN.SIMPEG_PEGAWAI.PANGKAT = ANGGARAN.SIMPEG_KODE_GOLONGAN_PANGKAT.ID_GOLONGAN_PANGKAT
    INNER JOIN (
      SELECT 
        ID_PEGAWAI,
        CONCAT(TO_CHAR(abs(sysdate - TO_DATE(TMT_JABATAN))/360,'9,999,999.9'),' TAHUN') MASA_KERJA, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID_PEGAWAI ORDER BY TMT_JABATAN DESC) rownumber
      FROM SIMPEG_JABATAN
    ) xxx
      ON ANGGARAN.SIMPEG_PEGAWAI.ID_PEGAWAI = xxx.ID_PEGAWAI
WHERE
  ANGGARAN.SIMPEG_PEGAWAI.ST_AKTIF = 1 AND
  ANGGARAN.SIMPEG_PEGAWAI.ESELON2 <> 1 AND
  ANGGARAN.SIMPEG_PEGAWAI.PANGKAT >= 12 AND 
  ANGGARAN.SIMPEG_ESELON_JABATAN.STATUS = 1 AND
  ANGGARAN.SIMPEG_ESELON_JABATAN.ID_ESELON2=2 AND
  xxx.rownumber = 1
ORDER BY ANGGARAN.SIMPEG_KODE_GOLONGAN_PANGKAT.SORT DESC
```

Comment: here is return result [Err] ORA-00904: "XXX"."ROWNUMBER": invalid identifier

Comment: not understand yet what you try to explian, would you like to show how could be done with my query above :)

Comment: Updated my answer. It is very difficult to write SQL code here, but i think what i mean is clear.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle does not support columns aliases in WHERE clauses (or similar situations like here). You have to name the column again (by its original name).

```
 select dummy as kode from dual where kode = 'X'

 >  ORA-00904: "KODE": invalid identifier
```

Comment: But this will work: `select * from (select dummy as kode from dual) a where kode = 'X'`

Comment: @ZZa: Yes, pushing the reference to the alias up to the consumer of the view it is declared in, makes it visible (otherwise, they wouldn't make any sense at all).

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign an alias in the level below to use it in a query (I haven't checked the syntax and workability of your query, just changed the part which is essential to answer your question):

```
SELECT
TMP.KODE,
TMP.NAMA,
TMP.NIP,
ANGGARAN.SIMPEG_ESELON_JABATAN.JABATAN,
ANGGARAN.SIMPEG_KODE_GOLONGAN_PANGKAT.GOLONGAN,
ANGGARAN.SIMPEG_KODE_GOLONGAN_PANGKAT.PANGKAT,
    (SELECT *
            FROM (SELECT CONCAT(TO_CHAR(abs(sysdate - TO_DATE(TMT_JABATAN))/360,'9,999,999.9'),' TAHUN') 
                FROM SIMPEG_JABATAN where ID_PEGAWAI=TMP.KODE ORDER BY TMT_JABATAN desc)
    WHERE ROWNUM = 1) AS MASA_KERJA
FROM 
(SELECT ANGGARAN.SIMPEG_PEGAWAI.ID_PEGAWAI AS KODE, ANGGARAN.SIMPEG_PEGAWAI.* FROM ANGGARAN.SIMPEG_PEGAWAI) TMP
    INNER JOIN ANGGARAN.SIMPEG_ESELON_JABATAN 
        ON TMP.ESELON_JABATAN = ANGGARAN.SIMPEG_ESELON_JABATAN.ID_ESELON_JABATAN
    INNER JOIN ANGGARAN.SIMPEG_KODE_GOLONGAN_PANGKAT 
        ON TMP.PANGKAT = ANGGARAN.SIMPEG_KODE_GOLONGAN_PANGKAT.ID_GOLONGAN_PANGKAT
WHERE
    TMP.ST_AKTIF = 1 AND
    TMP.ESELON2 <> 1 AND
    TMP.PANGKAT >= 12 AND 
    ANGGARAN.SIMPEG_ESELON_JABATAN.STATUS = 1 AND
    ANGGARAN.SIMPEG_ESELON_JABATAN.ID_ESELON2=2
ORDER BY
ANGGARAN.SIMPEG_KODE_GOLONGAN_PANGKAT.SORT DESC
```

Comment: i have tried your answer but the result come with [Err] ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Comment: Try again, not sure it's possible to assign aliases with dots, got rid of them.

Comment: diferent error code show up [Err] ORA-00904: "KODE": invalid identifier

Comment: Oups, didn't notice KODE column in a subquery, fixed.

Comment: still have same error code [Err] ORA-00904: "KODE": invalid identifier, is there another method to make it work ? one more step being crazy because of this :D